# How to prevent ipython shutting down interactive mode while running a script

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

This page talks about the usage of ipython for interactive plotting: http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html

According to that page, by default the %run command that is used to run scripts in ipython shuts down interactive mode. Is there an option to run the script in interactive mode as well?

I want the plotting commands in a script to take effect in the plotting figure as soon as they are run as if they are entered from the console interactively.

For example, consider the very simple script below:

```
# try.py:
# run in ipython that is started with 
# ipython --pylab
# using 
# %run -i try.py

from numpy import *
from time import sleep

ion()
x = randn(10000)
hist(x,100)
show()
sleep(5)
xlabel('labalu')
```

When run from ipython as indicated in the comment, this script waits 5 seconds, than shows everything. What I want is this: When run from ipython as indicated in the comment, the script should show the histogram immediately, wait 5 seconds, than update the figure to show the x label.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `ion()` so it is after `show()` does what I think you want. Why it doesn't in the higher position, I do not know offhand.

Comment: No. It does not. I am on windows 7 with python 2.7 by the way. Does this work on yours?

Comment: Yes, works for me on both Mac and Windows 8 (equivalent to Win7 for these purposes), both with Enthought Canopy (Python 2.7), with Qt as the pylab backend. This is with ipython 2.0. Did you remove the ion() at the beginning?

Comment: I did. May be my version of ipython is old or something: 0.13.1

Comment: well over a year old, indeed. Two major releases since. Strongly recommend an update.

Answer (score 0):

If wx is used as the backend, following works:

```
#run in ipython that is started with ipython --pylab=wx
from numpy import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WX')
import wx
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
x = np.random.uniform(0,1,100)
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
wx.Yield()
for i in reversed(range(5)):
    print(i)
    sleep(1)
plt.xlabel('labl')
wx.Yield()
```

So, `wx.Yield()` lets interaction with the figure window. This also works when the script is run with normal python, but the figure is closed at the end of the script automatically.

Any cross-backends solutions (or solutions for qt/tk ) are still well come.

Answer (score 0):

And below is a solution that works with both the wx and qt backends. gcf().canvas.flush_events() does the trick.

```
# try.py:
# run in ipython that is started with 
# ipython --pylab
# using 
# %run -i try.py

from numpy import *
import matplotlib
from time import sleep

x = randn(10000)
hist(x,100)
show()
ion()
gcf().canvas.flush_events() 
sleep(5)
xlabel('labalu')
show()
```